# Disable the firing of touchcancel in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, touch, android-browser

I am making a mobile website that uses JavaScript touch events. Things work fine in iOS Safari and Chrome for Android, but the stock Android Browser (version 4.1.2) is giving me trouble.

During a touch process, the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events are called as expected. However, one of the actions performed by the `touchmove` handler seems to trigger a premature `touchcancel` event. (I'm not sure whether this is significant, but the action that triggers the `touchcancel` is the modification of an SVG object's `viewBox` attribute.) If I comment out this action, the touch process proceeds normally (i.e., completion of `touchmove` through to `touchend`).

All of my touch handlers call the `preventDefault()` function, so the issue isn't the one that's described in this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827.

I've read that there is a lot of [inconsistency among browsers](http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/12/23/different-ways-to-trigger-touchcancel-in-mobile-browsers/) as to when `touchcancel` is called. The stock Android browser is the only one that is problematic for me.

Is there a workaround out there? For example, is there away I can completely disable the `touchcancel` event? Another idea I had was to have the `touchcancel` handler programmatically trigger another `touchstart`/`touchmove` event, but I didn't get very far with that. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Argh! I think this problem has now migrated to Chrome Browser! It appeared in Version 28. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260732.

Comment: See also this post, which seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944197/android-browser-touchcancel-being-fired-althought-touchmove-has-preventdefault

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in Chrome Browser now, interfering with using Hammer.js. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Complain here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=372357

Comment: For future reference, the answer here works perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367854/html5-android-touchcancel

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit late but if someonee else is facing this issue, [here's a small jQuery extension](https://github.com/andreszs/jquery.events.swipe) that explains how to deal with `pointercancel` and `touchcancel` events.

Basically, if you switch to **pointer events** you will be able to prevent `pointercancel` by simply using the `touch-action` CSS property with a value of `none`, as long as the browser has both features correctly implemented. (Android 5+, Chrome 55+, IE11, Edge, etc)

If you really must use the legacy **touch events** instead, you'll have to implement `event.preventDefault()` in your touchmove events and this will prevent `touchcancel` from firing, but it will also disable entirely the browser handling of any default action like a pan or click.

As a final note, I wouldn't use **touch events + touch-action CSS rules** because `touch-action` was only recently added, at the same that that Pointer Events. So while that combination *may work in newer browsers*, it will most certainly *fail in older ones* (by triggering `touchcancel` event unexpectedly).

Check the README from the jQuery extension I posted because it explains the implications of using either TouchEvent and PointerEvent interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are useing hammer.js, you can disable pointer-events (which cause problems like this), by adding:
`delete window.PointerEvent;`
in your index.html PRIOR to loading hammer.js, and it will ignore those events.
You can also set SUPPORT_POINTER_EVENTS = false; (line 384 of v2.0.8) to do the same thing.
Ideally the devs would add the ability to turn this off, but so goes the open source dilemma...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I am fighting with the Chrome (Android) touchcancel behaviour since days and this is the first solution that really solved my issues with hammer.js.

Comment: are you kidding me!?  I can't believe this worked.  How insane! I have spent three days trying to troubleshoot why my UI was horked and this simple k̶l̶u̶d̶g̶e̶ fix solved it?  wow.... just.... wow....

Answer (score 0):

I think touchcansel is special event that triggers when user touched button in specific behavior.

Ex. User touch button, but didn't removed his finger from display on exactly that button, instead of this he could move it a bit to the left, and end his action there. In that case touchcancel would appear.

So if you don't want that action to fire, i think you have to remove all handlers that connected with that action in android browser.

$('selector').off('touchcancel'), of if it's delefated $('parent').undelegate('touchcancel','selector')

I don't think that there is problem with e.preventDefault(). Only may be if you click on a link, and page starts to reload. May be page is reloaded when you click on button? and you wait for some actions after page reloaded, you actually may not understand, that it happend.

Comment: [Touchcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel) will be inevitably fired by the browser, and trying to cancel or preventDefault inside it won't work as intended.