# Dragging an element with hammer.js fails on mobile

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm working on an interface to allow the user to drag an object around the screen using hammer.js.   In a desktop browser it works, but on mobile when I start dragging it works briefly, then suddenly acts as if the event's client coordinates suddenly went to 0,0.

I've got a simple SVG circle I'm trying to drag:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 640 480" id="svg" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; top:0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
  <circle class="selhan" cx="320" cy="240" r="200" id="circ" 
   style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); pointer-events: all; 
   touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; 
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  </circle>
</svg>
```

I'm setting up a simple `pan` handler:

```
var circ = document.getElementById("circ")
var Hn1=new Hammer(circ, {/*domEvents:true*/})
Hn1.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0, pointers:1 }) )
var X0,Y0
Hn1.on("panstart", function(e) {
    var ob = e.target
    var cx = ob.getAttribute("cx")
    var cy = ob.getAttribute("cy")
    X0=e.center.x-cx
    Y0=e.center.y-cy
})

Hn1.on("pan", function(e) {
        var ob = e.target
        var X = e.center.x-X0
        var Y = e.center.y-Y0
        ob.setAttribute("cx",X)
        ob.setAttribute("cy",Y)    
})
```

I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt4d27ho/30/) to demonstrate.  On mobile, if I put my finger in the center of the circle and move very slowly I see the circle track for a brief period of time, but then suddenly the center jumps to 0,0, whereas on desktop it follows the pointer around all day.

I created an [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt4d27ho/39/) which displays when `panstart`, `pancancel`, and `panend` events occur.  What I am seeing is that when the circle jumps to the origin I am getting a `pancancel` event.  Why is my pan being cancelled even though I haven't lifted my finger from the screen?

<s>Even stranger is [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/zt4d27ho/41/).  All I did was reverse the order of the spans (which display counters of how many times `panstart`, `pancancel`, and `panend` have occurred).  If the spans come *after* the SVG, then suddenly I can pan the circle, but *only* horizontally.  But if the spans come *before* or aren't there, then panning gets abruptly cancelled after a short amount of finger movement.</s> Ok, turns out it's the element that is scrolling, not the circle.  However, version 41 behaves strangely on desktop too... when I first tried it, I couldn't get it to respond to mouse events at all, but then it started working, and then it stopped again, all by simply changing to different versions and back.

Update: In an attempt to get to the bottom of why the `pancancel` callback is being called, I instrumented my copy of [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js).  The PanRecognizer `directionTest` function (line 1778) is returning false, causing the cancel to be generated.  What happens is always some form of "nothing happened", resulting in `hasMoved` being false, or distance being 0 (I tried setting threshold to -1, but this just moved where the problem showed up), or direction being DIRECTION_NONE.

This still doesn't make a lot of sense - I see this happen even when I'm panning at a fast enough rate that I should never get zero movement between two events, and even if I was panning slowly I wouldn't expect this to be a problem.

Update 2:
I added the following instrumentation:

```
    Hn1.on("hammer.input",function(ev) {
        console.log("debug",ev)
    })
```

When I do this, I see a source event [`pointercancel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointercancel) which suggests that the browser is cancelling the pointer motion in the middle of is actually being used.  In reviewing the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointercancel) for this event, none of the four reasons mentioned for a pointer event being cancelled applies in this case.  What is going on here?!

Comment: FWIW I have found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561100/543873) although I'm still up for a better description of why this happens, and a solution that maybe isn't so kludgy.

Answer (score 2):

Michael, I ran into the same problem as you. I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1182) on GitHub with example and video. Interesting to see you uncovered it has something to do with "pointercancel" being triggered by the browser, but so far it hasn't helped me figure out how to patch this issue. Did you make any progress on the matter?

For reference, this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266748/disable-the-firing-of-touchcancel-in-android-browser) talks about the same issue. Unfortunately, none of the fixes has so far worked for me for HammerJS.

EDIT:
It turns out that preventing the default "touchmove" event handling on the window will solve this problem for any SVG element on the page. That's great news, but it also disables all scrolling behaviour on the page. What I've done instead is catching the "touchmove" event on the SVG object, so any descendants in it will pan properly. I'm not yet sure if it has any bad side effects, but so far it has meant that my panning in SVG finally works on Android browsers!

For completeness' sake, here is the necessary code:

```
const options = { passive: false }; // needed because Chrome has this set to "true" by default for "touchmove" events
    mySVG.addEventListener(
      "touchmove",
      e => e.preventDefault(),
      options
    );
```

Comment: currently the progress I have made has been to not use Hammer, as the types of things we actually need to look at wound up needing don't really need the full gesture support hammer provides

Comment: Cool, happy you found a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered that I just need to add  jquery.ui.touch-punch.js and it works fine on mobile

library:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Not sure I understand... hammer.js doesn't have any other library requirements like jQuery.  are you suggesting I replace hammer with jQuery and touch punch?